# Can I change the datatype of a field Caller Street from text to picklist will the value in that field be lost?

Tags: data-types

Can I change the datatype of a field Caller Street from text to picklist. Will the previous data be lost

Please suggest

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce has a published list of field type conversions where data loss can occur. Converting from Text to a Picklist is one of the conversions where you will lose data.

SFDC Help Docs: [Notes on Changing Custom Field Types](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=notes_on_changing_custom_field_types.htm)